# Java add Typewriter effect to JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, timer

I need to display output to a JTextArea one character at a time, with a slight delay between each character. My attempt is as follows:

```
 private static void printInput(final String input)
{
        Timer timer = new Timer(60,new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                for(int i = 0; i<input.length(); i++)
                {
                    messageArea.append(Character.toString(input.charAt(i)));
                }
            }
        });
}
```

There are similar questions however I could not find one with an example I could use to figure out my problem

Comment: A `Timer` is pseudo loop, that is, each cycle is an iteration through the loop, this means you need to update the UI, update the loop condition and repeat as required

Answer (score 1):

A `Timer` is a pseudo loop, that it is, it triggers an cycle after a predefined delay, each cycle is an iteration of the loop and each iteration you need to update the UI and update the iterator value.

Now, because I don't like working in the `static` context, the first thing I suggest is you wrap up the basic concept into a separate class.  This way you can easily encapsulate the state

```
public class TypeWriter {
    private Timer timer;
    private int characterIndex = 0;
    private String input;
    private JTextArea textArea;

    public TypeWriter(JTextArea textArea, String input) {
        this.textArea = textArea;
        this.input = input;
        timer = new Timer(60, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (characterIndex < input.length()) {
                    textArea.append(Character.toString(input.charAt(characterIndex)));
                    characterIndex++;
                } else {
                    stop();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void start() {
        textArea.setText(null);
        characterIndex = 0;
        timer.start();
    }

    public void stop() {
        timer.stop();
    }

}
```

So, this is pretty basic, all this does is, using a `Timer`, check to see if there are any more characters that need to be printed, if there is, it takes the next character and appends it to the text area and updates the iterator value. If we're at the end of the text, it will stop the `Timer` (ie, the exit condition)

Comment: Thank you so much for a quick response, and for providing a working example. On start, this sets the text area to null, I'm assuming this behavior can be safely left out?

Comment: @BenKramer It sets the "text" to `null` and yes, it's a common practice when you want to clear a text component.  You could use `""` to get the same result; Because of the way text components work, they will never return `null` from `getText`

Comment: I tried creating two instances managed under a synchronized keyword as follows: 
        synchronized(messageArea){
        new TypeWriter(messageArea,"Testing").start();
        new TypeWriter(messageArea,"“In the beginning the universe was created, this has made a lot of people very\nangry and been widely regarded as a bad move.”-Douglas Adams").start();

however this doesn't force each one to 'wait its turn'

Comment: No, I wouldn't think so.  I'd add a observer pattern to the `TypeWriter` class which could generate "start"/"stopped" events, I would then start the first class and when it triggers a "stopped" event, start the next one, basically chain one to the other

Comment: I'm not great at programming and this approach seems a bit ambitious to me. Is there a less ambitious method, even if less efficient, that I could try?

Comment: So, basically as I understand it, you have a series of `String`s you want to type out, for whatever reason, you can't use a single `String`. There are a number of ways to you might achieve this.  You could use a single `Timer` which takes a `String` from `List` of some kind and prints it.  Each time it completes a `String`, it pulls the next one from the `List`, when no more `String`s exist, it stops